# Code::Blocks, ld.exe error "Cannot find -lgomp"

Tags: gcc, openmp, codeblocks, ld

I'm trying to learn how to use openMP but I keep getting errors while using Code::Blocks.

I installed the MinGW version as recommended, and set up the Compiler as following.

Settings -> Compiler -> Compiler Settings -> Other options , added -fopenmp.

Then in Linker settings -> Other linker options added -lgomp.

When trying to build the program, I get the message

> ld.exe||cannot find -lgomp|
>
> ld.exe||cannot find -lgomp|
> ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

I'm using the GNU GCC Compiler, the program I'm trying to run is the following.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
int nthreads, tid;

#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)
  {

  tid = omp_get_thread_num();
  printf("Hello World from thread = %d\n", tid);

  if (tid == 0) 
    {
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
    }

  }

}
```

I tried many solutions posted online but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure for MinGW, but at least for regular GCC it automatically includes the -lgomp into the link flags whenever you use -fopenmp. So, try without adding -lgomp. If that does not work, the other alternative is that you add -L*path* where *path* is the location for the libgomp library (typically within the libraries for the compiler itself).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, eventually I retried with the regular gcc and it worked fine, there were some missing files.